# Different actions count returned in every request

Tags: action, rpc, api

I launched private EOS network with [bios boot tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence).
Then I pushed some transactions to the network. Now I want to retrieve **all** actions for an account `useraaaaaaah`. But every time I make a request to `/v1/history/get_actions` I get different actions count. Of course when I make requests there's no running processes pushing transactions to the network so actions' count must be same every time.

Example:

```
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
146
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
148
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
142
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
141
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
143
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
136
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
142
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
147
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
145
aleksey:~ aleksey$ curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/history/get_actions -d '{"account_name": "useraaaaaaag", "pos": -1, "offset": -200}' | jq '.actions | length'
140
```

I tried to change `pos` and `offset` params but id didn't help.
I found out that it works as expected only when `offset <= 100`. But this way I can't get all actions.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the [deprecated history plugin][1], or the [new state_hisory plugin][2]?


  [1]: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/history_api_plugin
  [2]: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/state_history_plugin

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your computer, the get_actions method will be finished when max time arrived, in default, it is 100ms, so if your computer is not in performance, it will only return few actions than you want.